# Calculate a serie in python

Tags: python-3.x

n is a knwon integer.
I need to print the serie:

`Sn = 1/n + 2/(n-1) + 3/(n-2) + ... + n`.

I tried:

```
n =2
soma =1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if n>i:        
        soma+=i/n + i/(n-1)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it like this for now:
(1/2 + 1/1) + (2/2 + 2/1) .....

When actually what you want is to accumulate only one of them each iteration.
Therefore: `soma+=i/(n-(i-1))`

Also the condition n>i is always true in that case so you can try and omit it.

Comment: there is a  division by zero so i think we need the condition n>i

Comment: In his formula yes you are right, but in my fixed formula there is no zero division.

Comment: I did not understand your formula!

Comment: Instead of adding two integers to soma each iteration you only need to add one, and try replacing real integers in my formula you'll see that it is exactly what you need for this series.